# Como puedo obtener la matriz de distancia intertopica del paquete LDAvis

Tags: r, jsonobject

Estoy corriendo el siguiente código

```
library(topicmodels)
lda <- LDA( dtmsgw1, k = 50, method = "Gibbs", 
            control = list(seed = 1234, burnin = 100, thin = 100, iter = 1000) )


library(LDAvis)

topicmodels2LDAvis <- function(x, ...){
  post <- topicmodels::posterior(x)
  if (ncol(post[["topics"]]) < 3) stop("The model must contain > 2 topics")
  mat <- x@wordassignments
  LDAvis::createJSON(
    phi = post[["terms"]], 
    theta = post[["topics"]],
    vocab = colnames(post[["terms"]]),
    doc.length = slam::row_sums(mat, na.rm = TRUE),
    term.frequency = slam::col_sums(mat, na.rm = TRUE),
    R=20
  )
}

serVis(topicmodels2LDAvis(lda))
```

Pero no se como obtener la matriz de distancia utilizada para crear el grafico de distancia intertopica

[image: grafica de distancias intertopicas]